# Is there a generic input event in WPF?

Tags: wpf, events, input

I'm creating a WPF application and I need to do something when I get some user input (it may be keyboard, mouse, ...) my question is if WPF have a generic event that tells me if the user have entered some input or do I have to handle all the events (MouseMove, KeyDown, TouchDown, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `InputManager.PreProcessInput`/`PostProcessInput`.

Comment: Yes, that's it, but it is giving me more events that I want, for example, when application starts although no input is being sent it gives me a lot of InputReportEventArgs. Where do they come from?

Comment: @Escobar5 - Have no idea :) Try looking at the stack trace in the debugger when you receive a notification that you didn't expect to receive.